# What actions did Costigan Jr. take that made Madolyn perceive him as vulnerable?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-departed

In *The Departed* (2006), during a visit to Madolyn's residence, Costigan Jr asks about her moving plans and
Madolyn informs him that she has three weeks left on her lease. Costigan Jr questions
her decision, but Madolyn clarifies that she intends to move in with her boyfriend and
stresses the importance of making a committed choice:

> Costigan Jr: Move in with your boyfriend?
>
> Madolyn: Yes. Otherwise
> it's...
>
> Costigan Jr: Oh, I know, I know. I know.
>
> Madolyn: I have to
> say **your vulnerability** is really freaking me out right now. Is it
> real?

What actions did Costigan Jr. take that made Madolyn perceive him as vulnerable?

Comment: She's his *therapist*. They talk a lot, she knows how to analyze minds. She knows how he is. Just checking if it's feigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more about her reading his body language than what he is saying.

Moments before her assessment of his vulnerability, she is watching him as he looks around, defenses down, totally unlike the aggressive cop in her office.

[Bedroom Scene](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gJPGvigy50&t=71s)